# How can I solve this auto highlight with my mac, it happens with every window

Tags: macos, macbook, system-preferences

My Mac keeps auto selecting boxes

[image]

Answer (score 2):

& what's wrong with it doing that?

<kbd>Enter ⌅</kbd>  will Shut Down with no change to the selected item.

<kbd>Space</kbd>  will toggle the selected item.

This is standard Mac toolbox behaviour.

Additionally,  <kbd>Tab ⇥</kbd>   will toggle between active controls &  <kbd>Esc</kbd>   will cancel.

Answer (score 1):

This is perfectly normal behavior and happens in most Operating Systems, not just on a Mac.

Each dialog-box has a default control (regardless whether that control happens to be a button, a combo-box or in this case a check-mark).
Which control is default is determined by the programmer who wrote the software that displays the dialog.
The OS simply moves the focus to the default control. That happens in every dialog every time it is opened.

Whether or not the default control in this particular dialog is well chosen by the programmer is another matter. If you don't like how Apple does it in this dialog you will have to complain to Apple.